# ANTLR variable name and type information

Tags: python-3.x, antlr, antlr4

Im using the CPP14 grammar provided by ANTLR and this is how my modified assignment expression look like,

```
assignmentexpression
   : conditionalexpression                                     #otherassignments
   | logicalorexpression assignmentoperator initializerclause  #theassignments
   | throwexpression                                           #otherassignments
   ;
```

Imagine the simple code below,

```
FILE *test = open_file("./a.txt");
```

I visit Assignments and get `FILE*test=open_file`, if i dump the parse tree in JSON I will get the following.

```
    "theassignments": [
    {
    "logicalorexpression": [
    {
        "logicalandexpression": [
        {
        "inclusiveorexpression": [
        {
            "exclusiveorexpression": [
            {
            "andexpression": [
            {
                "equalityexpression": [
                {
                "relationalexpression": [
                {
                    "shiftexpression": [
                    {
                    "additiveexpression": [
                    {
                        "multiplicativeexpression": [
                        {
                        "multiplicativeexpression": [
                        {
                            "pmexpression": [
                            {
                            "castexpression": [
                            {
                                "unaryexpression": [
                                {
                                "otherPostfixexpression": [
                                {
                                    "primaryexpression": [
                                    {
                                    "idexpression": [
                                    {
                                        "unqualifiedid": [
                                        {
                                        "type": 133,
                                        "text": "FILE"
                                        }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                    ]
                                    }
                                    ]
                                }
                                ]
                                }
                                ]
                            }
                            ]
                            }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                        },
                        {
                        "type": 92,
                        "text": "*"
                        },
                        {
                        "pmexpression": [
                        {
                            "castexpression": [
                            {
                            "unaryexpression": [
                            {
                                "otherPostfixexpression": [
                                {
                                "primaryexpression": [
                                {
                                    "idexpression": [
                                    {
                                    "unqualifiedid": [
                                    {
                                        "type": 133,
                                        "text": "test"
                                    }
```

By looking at that tree I expect that `additiveexpression` must have `multiplicativeexpression` and `pmexpression`!
I can see the `multiplicativeexpression` but cannot find `pmexpression`, I don't understand the tree structure, How can I access `pmexpression`?

The result im looking for is, Is there any better way of getting the following result?

```
Type: FILE
Sign : * 
Name : test
```

Thanks

Comment: This is really confusing, I thought I start to understand how this work ... The `pmexpression` is there under `additiveexpression` just like `multiplicativeexpression` but I cannot access it,
```
        virtual antlrcpp::Any visitTheassignments(CPP14Parser::TheassignmentsContext *ctx) override {
...
            CPP14Parser::MultiplicativeexpressionContext *multiplvexprCtx = addtvexprCtx->additiveexpression();          // always return NULL

```

Comment: First, the rule "additiveexpression
   : multiplicativeexpression
   | additiveexpression '+' multiplicativeexpression
   | additiveexpression '-' multiplicativeexpression
   ;" never mentions "pmexpression" on the RHS. So, no, "pmexpression" is never a direct child of "additiveexpression". If you want to get to that, you need to get "multiplicativeexpression" first. Also, it's really hard to visualize the tree using JSON and because your indentation is messed up. You give a partial JSON structure, so I can't go and pretty print it. I recommend using anything else.

Comment: I tried to paste it here https://pastebin.com/cJUByyDm, I dont know how else I can show you the tree structure.
Thanks

Comment: Check Line 69 please.

Comment: Thanks, but I already added the dozens of ")", "]" closing braces to complete a valid JSON and pretty print it. The Pastebin file is hard to look at with an indentation level of 2 spaces. You can either write a simple recursive tree printer, i.e., print_tree(IParseTree node, int level=0), or use something like Antlr TestRig or Grun.Net. They help immensely with problems like this.

Comment: Yes, line 69 is a pmexpression, and the parent is a multiplicativeexpression, not an additiveexpression. If you want to verify, write a tree walker and print out the type of the parent of an additiveexpression.

Comment: What about the line 65? How can I access '*'? Im trying to parse C++ with C++ how can I run Grun to see the parse tree?

Thanks

Comment: So, assuming you're in enterAdditiveexpression(CPP14Parser::AdditiveexpressionContext ...), to get the child containing the "*", call "ctx->multiplicativeexpression()" to get a MultiplicativeexpressionContext * . Next, to get the node in the tree containing "*", call ctx->multiplicativeexpression()->Star()". Of course, you're going to have to test whether the child is null before you start dereferencing the pointer. Because most parse trees are so huge, I hardly look at one ever. I just look at the grammar and the access functions in CPP14Parser.h to get a particular child.

Comment: (PS---I can't understand how to get an asterisk to appear in my comments, so you're going to need to read past these errors. The html code for asterisk isn't working and "double quote asterisk double quote" is just swallowed up. Sorry.)

Comment: Thanks kaby79, your answers solved my problem.